# geting a file nme from another server

Tags: unix

I have few directories

```
ut1-2013.02.26-23.45.31
ut1-2013.02.20-06.09.28
ut1-2013.02.18-23.33.23
```

in `test1` server in `release` folder, I want to get the output as latest directory i.e `ut1-2013.02.26-23.45.31` out of these directories to `test2` server.

what command (command pipes) shall I use in command line of test2 server  to ssh to test1 server and get the latest directory as output of the command?

Is the directory name `ut1-2013.02.26-23.45.31`, satisfying all the naming conventions ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried `mkdir ut1-2013.02.26-23.45.31`? It is easy and works : ) However, it is normally used underscore in this cases: `ut1_2013.02.26-23.45.31`

Comment: I already have these directories in release folder in test1 server but I want to get the latest directory as the output of the command when I run the command from another server.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -r release
```

will list all of the names in reverse order, you can use

```
ls -r release | head -1
```

if you just want the "most recent" one.

```
ls release | tail -1
```

also works. (`-1` is short for `-n 1`.)

Comment: As `ls -r release | head -1 == ls release | tail -1`, but which one is faster?

Comment: Presumably `head -1` is faster, because it can stop after the first line.